# How to soundproof a window trickle vent?

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

[image: window]

Is it possible to soundproof this window by sealing this ventilation hole in way that is reversible without damage (it's a rented property).

Comment: yes, it is probably possible ... try plugging the vent with various materials ... see if sound levels are reduced

Comment: Trickle vent, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trickle_vent)

Comment: What materials would you suggest @jsotola?

Comment: i would use anything i have laying around ... start with something like crumpled newspaper ... this is just to determine if anything gives an acceptable difference in sound levels ... a tight fitting wood panel may work ... maybe some styrofoam